# LinkageError when calling webservice method

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, linkageerror

I have an apache servicemix (camel 2.9) route which calls a bean, that in turn makes a SOAP request. The SOAP code is generated via wsdl2java and works fine (cxf 2.4.0). The problem i have is when a SOAP fault is thrown, i get the following issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/soap/SOAPFault"
    at javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException.<init>(SOAPFaultException.java:28)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)[175:org.apache.cxf.bundle:2.5.0.fuse-7-061]
    at $Proxy120.catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove(Unknown Source)
    at com.boohoo.magento.MagentoProducts.deleteImageFromProduct(MagentoProducts.java:403)[769:magento-soap-api:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)[:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:340)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:237)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
```

From a bit of googling (my background is C#) the error seems to be stating that the class has been loaded multiple times, but i dont see see how this is possible since SOAPFaultException isnt one of my classes.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Look for a jar called `saaj-api.xml`. It contains classes which are also present in standard JRE (in `rt.jar`).

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand what you mean. Where should i look?

Comment: It is `saaj-api.jar`, not `.xml`. It looks like your application has loaded `javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault` both from `rt.jar` and from somewhere else. What external libraries do you use?

Comment: I think i've found the problem. My web services bundle (cxf 1.4) is showing that it uses another web services bundle (which is rpc, using axis 1.4) under "maven dependencies" in eclipse. Am not sure why this is, as the 2 bundles never talk to each other and a bit confused as it wont let me remove it...

Comment: I've updated the maven depedancies and my cxf bundle no longer references the rpc bundle. I've done a clean/install and restarted apache servicemix but still get the linkage error...

Comment: axis 1.4 has also reference to `axis-saaj-1.4.jar` can you post a result of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: Is it possible for us to use cxf to consume the c# web services. I heard from my friend that he had exceptions for it and went for jax ws in service mix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was a problem with servicemix config. See: http://fusesource.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=4016