# spring jar conflicts with Axis2 jars

Tags: java, spring, apache-axis, spring-ws, jettison

I'm getting below error where spring-ws jar is available but still I'm getting below error.( Spring 4.1.0, Axis 1.6.2)

```
failed spring-ws
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
        at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategies(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:114)
        at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:200)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initWebServiceMessageFactory(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:326)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:311)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.initFrameworkServlet(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:234)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:485)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:215)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:431)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
```

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information. What is the set of JARs included in your application, or if you are using Maven, what does your POM look like?

Comment: Sorry for not providing much details, Once I upgraded spring-ws to 2.0 version, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a version mismatch for your libraries. Check whether they are in correct versions. As per your question title please look at the below links.

[Spring webservicetemplate jar conflict issue with Axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944811/spring-webservicetemplate-jar-conflict-issue-with-axis2)

https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. My issue was resolved upon updating spring-ws to 2.0 version.