# Websphere 8.5 Linkage Issue

Tags: spring, soap, websphere, soap-client, linkage

I am using spring Webservicetemplate to access soap service. The soap client package has been deployed in websphere. The deployment was successful but its throwing following error during SOAP api invocation.

Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/xml/soap/SOAPElement.getElementQName()Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@69ddc3da" of class "org/springframework/ws/soap/saaj/SaajSoapElement" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@6d67c67c" of class "javax/xml/soap/SOAPElement" have different types for the method signature
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapElement.getName(SaajSoapElement.java:51)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.AbstractSoapMessage.getVersion(AbstractSoapMessage.java:89)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessage.setSoapAction(SaajSoapMessage.java:168)

Can anyone please assist ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LinkageError - loading contraint violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67532986/linkageerror-loading-contraint-violation)

Comment: Hi @Jarid, Thanks for the details. Yes, I have the parent last configuration. But I tried to remove xml-apis.jar and stax-apis.jar which had the reference of javx.xml.namespace.QName. Still the same issue exist

Comment: Sounds like there's still something in there with duplicate visibility - is the error completely identical, or are there different class loaders and/or a different method in the error text?